# Impersonate with IdentityServer, with having an actor claim for the impersonated user

Tags: c#, identityserver4, impersonation

Together with IdentityServer 4, we've successfully implemented impersonation.

**Implementation details**

- From our MVC application there are ACR values provided as "Impersonate:" while connection the IdentityServer.
- At our IdentityServer there is a component, deriving from `AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator`. It filters the ACR-impersonate value and does a sign in with the provided userid.
- After the sign in, it returns to the MVC application and a cookie is being set there.

This all works very well so far.

**What do we want**

For security reasons, we want add an extra claim *actor* to the token/cookie, which always tells that one is acting as someone else.

**Challenge we are facing**

At our MVC application, we are using refresh tokens to renew expired access tokens. The IdentityServer is being connected with providing a *client id*, *client secret* and the *refresh token*. The profile service at the IdentityServer isn't aware of the *actor* claim and provides only the regular claims.

How can we achieve that?

Comment: Pardon me asking, but what is "ACR"? I have not come across the term anywhere while working with OIDC.

Comment: What is the lifetime of your `access_token` with impersonation? FWIW, when I implemented impersonation in my OIDC system using IdentityServer4 there wasn't any need to renew/refresh impersonated sessions (the default for human-users was 1 hour, which was long enough for every use-case of impersonation) - if you're doing impersonation for longer than that then you should look at supporting `delegation` grants instead. (If a 1-hour `access_token` lifetime seems long, it's okay because we had "live" session revocations)

Comment: You can implement your own IProfileService within IDS4.

Comment: @Dai The "ACR" value variant for impersonation was recommended in some blog post by Brock Allen. Short description: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/authorize.html

Comment: @Dai You're absolutely right. We are also using default, 1-hour which should be far enough for doing all things demanded for impersonation.

Comment: Pardon me asking, how exactly do you sign in in the AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator component? I'm facing the same problem right now.

Comment: We are having our custom _ProfileService_ which implements _IProfileService_. There we're checking whether a request contains a specific claim type for that purpose. If yes, we add it to the requested claims of the context. Those are in turn being resolved by the `UserStore`.